# How to add a custom meta box below publish box in CPT that is like publish meta box and can contains html?

Tags: custom-post-types, metabox

How can i add a custom meta box below publish box in CPT that will be like publish meta box and contain some html code? See the attached shot for more info. [image]

Answer (score 1):

The key function and search key word is `add_meta_box()`. This function add additional meta boxes to a post type, also custom post type.

See the [codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_meta_box) for more about the parameters and also examples. You find also a lot of examples, how tos in the WWW and here on WPSE.

A simple example to understand it better, but without callback function `myplugin_meta_box_callback`, there handle your html, doing inside the meta box.

```
add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', 'myplugin_add_meta_box' );
/**
 * Adds a box to the main column on the Post and Page edit screens.
 */
function myplugin_add_meta_box() {

    $screens = array( 'custom_post_type', 'page' );

    foreach ( $screens as $screen ) {

        add_meta_box(
            'myplugin_section_id',
            __( 'My Meta Box Title', 'myplugin_textdomain' ),
            'myplugin_meta_box_callback',
            $screen
        );
    }
}
```